# Slick string sanitation

Tags: scala, slick

I want to perform a query using the SQL LIKE operation with a string parameter.
Example:

`coffee <- Coffees if coffee.name like s"%$queryString%"`

Is it safe?

Comment: This is safe from SQL injections, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Slick documentation :

> Slick’s key feature are type-safe, composable queries. Slick comes with a Scala-to-SQL compiler, which allows a (purely functional) sub-set of the Scala language to be compiled to SQL queries [...]
>
> The fact that such queries are type-safe not only catches many mistakes early at compile time, but also **eliminates the risk of SQL injection vulnerabilities**

I did no try myself, but I think you are safe even when using user params